# How do i rectify a wrong tx and an unconfirmed transaction?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

unconfirmed transaction - be3744d2be312e2e51ed6ac8f8ec5ea5695978ac5f729c52985191b1739cdbca

https://blockchain.info/tx/be3744d2be312e2e51ed6ac8f8ec5ea5695978ac5f729c52985191b1739cdbca

Problem  - unconfirmed transaction

cause    - probably because no fees were attached

solution - ???

My Satoshi client (BitcoinQt) is in-sync. Its been over 5 hrs now. Any solution will be appreciated. Unfortunately, I did not back up before i made this transaction.

UPDATE - I uploaded the private key onto blockchain to see a shocking new low balance.

After checking I realized that there was a problem with another tx as well. I sent out 50BTC but 89.68 was deducted

```
Status: 53 confirmations
Date: 4/3/13 14:51
To: 1JFxQV9eGesx6hn5jLSgdXKPquQLnNF9Cx
Debit: -50.00 BTC
Net amount: -50.00 BTC
Transaction ID: b17bbdd1b9dedbcff9ece48dd0feee7b8f210061f711b8e1d7d8c39c499f4660
```

https://blockchain.info/tx/b17bbdd1b9dedbcff9ece48dd0feee7b8f210061f711b8e1d7d8c39c499f4660

How do I get back the remainder? The other unconfirmed tx is still unconfirmed and has been over 10 hrs now.

Thanks in advance

EDIT - Problem solved guys, thanks.

Comment: Just like every single other unconfirmed transaction question, you couldn't be bothered to pay any transaction fees. Just wait, and after a few days, it should disappear and you can try again, and this time pay the fees.

Comment: yes i definitely will, any inputs on the other problem? the unconfirmed also has the same signs if u see the blockchain it says 10.32 - i understand this is change but in the other case i did not get it back.

Comment: Does the remainder show up in your wallet balance? Some clients will generate a new address (without telling you) and send some bitcoins to it when you send bitcoins to someone else.

Comment: on the blockchain e-wallet it doesn't - on the bitcoin Qt it does..do i receive bitcoins to that address?

Comment: How* do i receive?

Comment: It does it automatically. You have those leftover bitcoins in your wallet automatically.

Comment: You'd better edit out the first part of the question and focus on the second: posts with more than one question are frowned upon.